# How to correctly use AsyncStorage (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For example how to correctly store users like [{username: 'username', name: 'name', surname: 'surname'},{username: 'username1', name: 'name1', surname: 'surname1'}]? Only like this code or not?

```
     return AsyncStorage.getItem('users')
            .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
            .then(json => {
             json.push(newUser);
               return AsyncStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(json))
                    .then(json => console.log('success!'))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```